# How to begin with jar file in java code?

Tags: java, weka

I am beginner for using java. Actually, what means by "make sure that weka.jar, common math.jar and etc. directory was in your classpath"? I already installed jar file and follow instruction from other source to change at classpath at the environment variable in control panel. However, I am still cannot call that function in my java code.

Comment: Are you using an IDE or just text editor + command line?

Comment: Tell us which exception you are getting. e.g. `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: Try reading this Example in the Java Documentation site: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/5791/the-java-command-java-and-javaw/20506/running-a-java-application-with-library-dependencies#t=201612150509340869554

Comment: Hint: 1) using the CLASSPATH environment variable is not the best approach. 2) you would be better off learning / understanding what you are doing than blindly following some instructions

Comment: @kcazllerraf, I using notepat++ source ocede editor.

Comment: @VHS..When I run the source code, this error i get "error: package weka.core does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You need to import external jars to your project because these jars will be specific to your workspace and java compiler will look for these jars in your lib directory of your workspace.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have already import external jars 'import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import weka.core.*;' but I get this error "error: package weka.core does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import external jars to your project, try this:

First, select properties:

[image]

Second, select Java Build Path:

[image]

Third, select libraries:

[image]

And finally, add jar:

[image]